# Celery not automatically starting on Amazon Linux AMI 2013.03.1

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, celery, djcelery

I can't seem to automatically bootup my celeryd script located in /etc/init.d/celeryd everytime my Amazon Linux AMI 2013.03.1 machine is booted. I have to automatically do /etc/init.d/celeryd start . However, it boots perfectly and work right away.

Any ideas? I tried

sudo chkconfig /etc/init.d/celeryd on

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a simple `startup script`:

Create a file called celeryd.sh

```
vim /etc/init.d/celeryd.sh
```

Inside that file:

```
#!/bin/sh

##Starts the celery on boot up###
/etc/init.d/celeryd start
```

Change permission:

```
chmod +x celeryd.sh
```

Done.

You can do `init 6` and test, if it works or not.

More on : http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-how-to-run-a-command-when-boots-up.html